# *NgIf async object trigger else part

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm using `*ngIf` object to call multiple observables using `async pipe`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ obs1: obs1$| async, obs2: obs2$| async} as observables; else loader"> </ng-container>
```

Since this `*ngIf` will always be `truthy`, how can I load my spinner while waiting for `async pipe` to finish processing.

```
<ng-template #loader><app-spinner></app-spinner></ng-template>
```

I want to avoid nested `<ng-container></ng-container>` to call my multiple `observables`.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: I ended up splitting my observables into multiple levels, not elegant solution but served my needs.